# Sending XML Files via Flume (Using curl)

Tags: xml, http, flume-ng

I'm using Apache Flume to move data, I have set up an agent with an HTTP Source. I want this source to receive XML files, and these files will eventually be read by a sink which will push to Cassandra (My own sink). So i have added an HTTPSourceXMLHandler which handles xml files the way I want to. 
I have the following configuration file:

```
# Name the components on this agent
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type = http
a1.sources.r1.bind = localhost
a1.sources.r1.port = 44444
a1.sources.r1.handler = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSourceXMLHandler

# Describe the sink
a1.sinks.k1.type = file_roll
a1.sinks.k1.sink.directory = /home/admin/Desktop/XMLs
a1.sinks.k1.rollInterval = 5 

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

I have a source on localhost port 44444, a channel, and a file sink (for now, I just want Flume sink to save the xml in my local machine for performance testing). 
When I use curl to send an example xml file (ex.xml), the operation succeeds, however the sink does not save it as a file on the specified location:
curl -X POST -d @ex.xml http://localhost:44444

Am I doing something wrong? The XMLHandler is working well and was tested.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, can you please post your sink and handler code so we can take a closer look and see if we can spot anything?  Thanks.